# Debugging all methods in abstract class

Tags: java, json, event-listener

I am currently working on my own API for a game I am using the `java.nio.file.WatchService` to listen to file changes on the latest modified file. For Event registering, I am using an abstract class that can be extended to override the event methods

https://pastebin.com/CCjxehfb

For building the API object I made this class which saves the register eventListener classes and whenever the new string that has been added to the file is one of the registered EvenListeners types it will fire the method and all the code written inside of it.

https://pastebin.com/cegR2zX9

my problem now is I want to add a way for users to run the `runTest` method which will register all of the events in the `EventListener` class.

What I want it to do is to run through all the files and whenever it throws an exception I know that that event is reading the JSON string wrong or is missing values in its a string.

```
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:13Z", "event":"FSSSignalDiscovered", "type":"DEBUGTEST23", "SystemAddress":11666339210689, "SignalName":"Schwann Dock", "IsStation":true }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:13Z", "event":"Music", "MusicTrack":"NoTrack" }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:14Z", "event":"Missions", "Active":[  ], "Failed":[  ], "Complete":[  ] }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:14Z", "event":"Loadout", "Ship":"cutter", "ShipID":15, "ShipName":"Invictus", "ShipIdent":"oi-inv", "HullValue":175924977, "ModulesValue":221463348, "HullHealth":1.000000, "UnladenMass":1630.399902, "CargoCapacity":512, "MaxJumpRange":42.644478, "FuelCapacity":{ "Main":64.000000, "Reserve":1.160000 }, "Rebuy":19869418, "Modules":[ { "Slot":"ShipCockpit", "Item":"cutter_cockpit", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"CargoHatch", "Item":"modularcargobaydoor", "On":true, "Priority":2, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"LargeHardpoint2", "Item":"hpt_mininglaser_fixed_medium", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"LargeHardpoint1", "Item":"hpt_mininglaser_fixed_medium", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"HugeHardpoint1", "Item":"hpt_mininglaser_fixed_medium", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint1", "Item":"hpt_shieldbooster_size0_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128673780, "BlueprintName":"ShieldBooster_HeavyDuty", "Level":1, "Quality":0.965700, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":7.000000, "OriginalValue":3.500000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":49.439999, "OriginalValue":48.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":1.260000, "OriginalValue":1.200000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"DefenceModifierShieldMultiplier", "Value":31.712008, "OriginalValue":20.000004, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint2", "Item":"hpt_shieldbooster_size0_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128673780, "BlueprintName":"ShieldBooster_HeavyDuty", "Level":1, "Quality":1.000000, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":7.000000, "OriginalValue":3.500000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":49.439999, "OriginalValue":48.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":1.260000, "OriginalValue":1.200000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"DefenceModifierShieldMultiplier", "Value":32.000004, "OriginalValue":20.000004, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint3", "Item":"hpt_shieldbooster_size0_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128673780, "BlueprintName":"ShieldBooster_HeavyDuty", "Level":1, "Quality":0.987100, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":7.000000, "OriginalValue":3.500000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":49.439999, "OriginalValue":48.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":1.260000, "OriginalValue":1.200000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"DefenceModifierShieldMultiplier", "Value":31.892002, "OriginalValue":20.000004, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint4", "Item":"hpt_shieldbooster_size0_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128673780, "BlueprintName":"ShieldBooster_HeavyDuty", "Level":1, "Quality":1.000000, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":7.000000, "OriginalValue":3.500000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":49.439999, "OriginalValue":48.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":1.260000, "OriginalValue":1.200000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"DefenceModifierShieldMultiplier", "Value":32.000004, "OriginalValue":20.000004, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint5", "Item":"hpt_shieldbooster_size0_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128673780, "BlueprintName":"ShieldBooster_HeavyDuty", "Level":1, "Quality":1.000000, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":7.000000, "OriginalValue":3.500000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":49.439999, "OriginalValue":48.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":1.260000, "OriginalValue":1.200000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"DefenceModifierShieldMultiplier", "Value":32.000004, "OriginalValue":20.000004, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint6", "Item":"hpt_heatsinklauncher_turret_tiny", "On":true, "Priority":0, "AmmoInClip":1, "AmmoInHopper":2, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint7", "Item":"hpt_chafflauncher_tiny", "On":true, "Priority":0, "AmmoInClip":1, "AmmoInHopper":10, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"TinyHardpoint8", "Item":"hpt_plasmapointdefence_turret_tiny", "On":true, "Priority":0, "AmmoInClip":12, "AmmoInHopper":10000, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"PaintJob", "Item":"paintjob_cutter_fullmetal_malachite", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Decal1", "Item":"decal_explorer_elite", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Decal2", "Item":"decal_explorer_elite", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Decal3", "Item":"decal_explorer_elite", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipName0", "Item":"nameplate_explorer03_black", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipName1", "Item":"nameplate_explorer03_black", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipID0", "Item":"nameplate_shipid_doubleline_black", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipID1", "Item":"nameplate_shipid_doubleline_black", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Armour", "Item":"cutter_armour_grade1", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"PowerPlant", "Item":"int_powerplant_size8_class5", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"MainEngines", "Item":"int_engine_size8_class2", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Professor Palin", "EngineerID":300220, "BlueprintID":128673659, "BlueprintName":"Engine_Dirty", "Level":5, "Quality":1.000000, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":102.000000, "OriginalValue":120.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":9.072001, "OriginalValue":8.100000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"EngineOptimalMass", "Value":2205.000000, "OriginalValue":2520.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"EngineOptPerformance", "Value":140.000000, "OriginalValue":100.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"EngineHeatRate", "Value":2.080000, "OriginalValue":1.300000, "LessIsGood":1 } ] } }, { "Slot":"FrameShiftDrive", "Item":"int_hyperdrive_size7_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128673694, "BlueprintName":"FSD_LongRange", "Level":5, "Quality":1.000000, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":104.000000, "OriginalValue":80.000000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":139.400009, "OriginalValue":164.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"PowerDraw", "Value":1.035000, "OriginalValue":0.900000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"FSDOptimalMass", "Value":4185.000000, "OriginalValue":2700.000000, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"LifeSupport", "Item":"int_lifesupport_size7_class2", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"PowerDistributor", "Item":"int_powerdistributor_size7_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"The Dweller", "EngineerID":300180, "BlueprintID":128673738, "BlueprintName":"PowerDistributor_HighFrequency", "Level":4, "Quality":0.953300, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"WeaponsCapacity", "Value":58.559998, "OriginalValue":61.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"WeaponsRecharge", "Value":8.270380, "OriginalValue":6.100000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"EnginesCapacity", "Value":39.360001, "OriginalValue":41.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"EnginesRecharge", "Value":5.423200, "OriginalValue":4.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"SystemsCapacity", "Value":39.360001, "OriginalValue":41.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"SystemsRecharge", "Value":5.423200, "OriginalValue":4.000000, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"Radar", "Item":"int_sensors_size7_class2", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000, "Engineering":{ "Engineer":"Felicity Farseer", "EngineerID":300100, "BlueprintID":128740671, "BlueprintName":"Sensor_LightWeight", "Level":3, "Quality":1.000000, "Modifiers":[ { "Label":"Mass", "Value":16.000000, "OriginalValue":32.000000, "LessIsGood":1 }, { "Label":"Integrity", "Value":73.500000, "OriginalValue":105.000000, "LessIsGood":0 }, { "Label":"SensorTargetScanAngle", "Value":25.500000, "OriginalValue":30.000000, "LessIsGood":0 } ] } }, { "Slot":"FuelTank", "Item":"int_fueltank_size6_class3", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot01_Size8", "Item":"int_cargorack_size8_class1", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot02_Size8", "Item":"int_cargorack_size8_class1", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot03_Size6", "Item":"int_fuelscoop_size6_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot04_Size6", "Item":"int_shieldgenerator_size6_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot05_Size6", "Item":"int_dronecontrol_collection_size5_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot06_Size5", "Item":"int_dronecontrol_collection_size5_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot07_Size5", "Item":"int_guardianfsdbooster_size5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot08_Size4", "Item":"int_refinery_size4_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot09_Size3", "Item":"int_dronecontrol_prospector_size3_class5", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Slot10_Size1", "Item":"int_detailedsurfacescanner_tiny", "On":true, "Priority":0, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"PlanetaryApproachSuite", "Item":"int_planetapproachsuite", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"Bobble01", "Item":"bobble_pilotmale", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipKitSpoiler", "Item":"cutter_shipkit1_spoiler2", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipKitWings", "Item":"cutter_shipkit1_wings2", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"ShipKitBumper", "Item":"cutter_shipkit1_bumper4", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"WeaponColour", "Item":"weaponcustomisation_blue", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"EngineColour", "Item":"enginecustomisation_blue", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 }, { "Slot":"VesselVoice", "Item":"voicepack_archer", "On":true, "Priority":1, "Health":1.000000 } ] }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:14Z", "event":"Music", "MusicTrack":"Exploration" }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:14Z", "event":"Statistics", "Bank_Account":{ "Current_Wealth":1824776968, "Spent_On_Ships":2270921684, "Spent_On_Outfitting":3890744470, "Spent_On_Repairs":9227445, "Spent_On_Fuel":153131, "Spent_On_Ammo_Consumables":83703, "Insurance_Claims":18, "Spent_On_Insurance":97841625, "Owned_Ship_Count":4 }, "Combat":{ "Bounties_Claimed":58, "Bounty_Hunting_Profit":3952507, "Combat_Bonds":0, "Combat_Bond_Profits":0, "Assassinations":0, "Assassination_Profits":0, "Highest_Single_Reward":273702, "Skimmers_Killed":14 }, "Crime":{ "Notoriety":0, "Fines":62, "Total_Fines":53350, "Bounties_Received":19, "Total_Bounties":36550, "Highest_Bounty":10000 }, "Smuggling":{ "Black_Markets_Traded_With":5, "Black_Markets_Profits":252530, "Resources_Smuggled":7, "Average_Profit":50506, "Highest_Single_Transaction":251811 }, "Trading":{ "Markets_Traded_With":20, "Market_Profits":1036230369, "Resources_Traded":5776, "Average_Profit":31400920.272727, "Highest_Single_Transaction":242136270 }, "Mining":{ "Mining_Profits":841642977, "Quantity_Mined":2010, "Materials_Collected":7891 }, "Exploration":{ "Systems_Visited":3741, "Exploration_Profits":215465944, "Planets_Scanned_To_Level_2":3902, "Planets_Scanned_To_Level_3":4343, "Efficient_Scans":12, "Highest_Payout":3895647, "Total_Hyperspace_Distance":165133, "Total_Hyperspace_Jumps":4376, "Greatest_Distance_From_Start":25843.918303409, "Time_Played":3015420 }, "Passengers":{ "Passengers_Missions_Accepted":307, "Passengers_Missions_Disgruntled":29, "Passengers_Missions_Bulk":10, "Passengers_Missions_VIP":1444, "Passengers_Missions_Delivered":1454, "Passengers_Missions_Ejected":61 }, "Search_And_Rescue":{ "SearchRescue_Traded":5, "SearchRescue_Profit":85364, "SearchRescue_Count":4 }, "TG_ENCOUNTERS":{ "TG_ENCOUNTER_TOTAL":3, "TG_ENCOUNTER_TOTAL_LAST_SYSTEM":"Witch Head Sector KC-V c2-1", "TG_ENCOUNTER_TOTAL_LAST_TIMESTAMP":"3305-11-08 05:22", "TG_ENCOUNTER_TOTAL_LAST_SHIP":"Imperial Cutter", "TG_SCOUT_COUNT":3 }, "Crafting":{ "Count_Of_Used_Engineers":6, "Recipes_Generated":421, "Recipes_Generated_Rank_1":112, "Recipes_Generated_Rank_2":64, "Recipes_Generated_Rank_3":83, "Recipes_Generated_Rank_4":76, "Recipes_Generated_Rank_5":86 }, "Crew":{ "NpcCrew_TotalWages":7653322, "NpcCrew_Hired":3, "NpcCrew_Fired":3 }, "Multicrew":{ "Multicrew_Time_Total":6838, "Multicrew_Gunner_Time_Total":742, "Multicrew_Fighter_Time_Total":0, "Multicrew_Credits_Total":14771, "Multicrew_Fines_Total":0 }, "Material_Trader_Stats":{ "Trades_Completed":33, "Materials_Traded":753, "Encoded_Materials_Traded":210, "Raw_Materials_Traded":105, "Grade_1_Materials_Traded":114, "Grade_2_Materials_Traded":65, "Grade_3_Materials_Traded":172, "Grade_4_Materials_Traded":195, "Grade_5_Materials_Traded":207 } }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:14Z", "event":"Music", "MusicTrack":"NoTrack" }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:55:16Z", "event":"Cargo", "Vessel":"Ship", "Count":94, "Inventory":[ { "Name":"drones", "Name_Localised":"Limpet", "Count":94, "Stolen":0 } ] }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T10:58:20Z", "event":"FSDTarget", "Name":"LTT 6528", "SystemAddress":2870246188481 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:00:25Z", "event":"FSDTarget", "Name":"LHS 3182", "SystemAddress":908553360098 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:01:50Z", "event":"LaunchDrone", "Type":"Prospector" }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:01:55Z", "event":"Cargo", "Vessel":"Ship", "Count":93 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:02:43Z", "event":"ReservoirReplenished", "FuelMain":58.200001, "FuelReservoir":1.160000 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:02:57Z", "event":"FSDTarget", "Name":"LTT 5990", "SystemAddress":3932210369250 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:06:09Z", "event":"FSDTarget", "Name":"LPM 607", "SystemAddress":2999791389043 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-05-09T11:07:09Z", "event":"FSDTarget", "Name":"LTT 5990", "SystemAddress":3932210369250 }
```

this is what the program is reading and it will fire the events depending on the string in the `" event":` value of the JSON string.
Your help is much appreciated and I hope I didn't overcomplicate my question.

Comment: Please update your question with code rather than pasting external links.

Comment: There is a limit of 30000 characters...